# How can I download arbitrary files to the SD card on my phone?

Tags: downloading, files

So I have an android phone, and I wanted to download some files on it that are not currently accessible from my PC (corporate firewall).  The thinking is that once the files are on the phone, I can easily connect the PC to the phone to access the files.  The problem I have is that the phone refuses to download the files, claiming that

```
"Cannot Download.  The content is not supported on this phone."
```

So how can I get the content onto the phone?  I know the phone will be unable to run these files meaningfully;  I just want them downloaded and stored for later access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a file from a website, you should probably try to use a different browser. [Opera Mini](http://www.appbrain.com/app/opera-mini-browser/com.opera.mini.android) for example uses a different download manager (not the native one) so it doesn't refuse to download any files.

If you want to move them over from a PC, try some of [those methods](http://droidreign.com/2010/09/sync-and-copy-files-between-your-pc-and-your-android-phone/).

Comment: Quite correct;  the Opera Mini browser downloaded the files with no problem, and saved them on the SD card.

Answer (score 2):

The ASTRO file manager has an option "Allow the Web browser to download any type of file". I think that does what you (and me and everybody else) wants, but haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

use awesome drop. You only need to install the awesome drop app from the market, then go to http://labs.dashwire.com/drop, and then enter the pin given in the webpage to your app, et voila you can transfer any file from your PC to phone over the internet.

edit: there is an intro video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=futRwfTEQe8).

Comment: That looks like useful software, but it assumes that I already have the file, and want to move it to the phone.  Actually, I don't have the file, and want to download it onto my phone from a remote webserver.  Good link though!